# Initializing array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, shuffle

I have a Deck object (deck of cards) which is a double-ended queue implemented as a doubly-linked list.  I would like to be able to shuffle the queue at will, but the way I would go about it is beyond me.  So instead I've opted to pre-shuffle an array a pointers to the cards and enqueue them after the fact.  Problem is, the code I have now doesn't seem to be initializing the pointers at all.

```
void BuildDeck(Deck* deck) {
    Card** cards = new Card*[20];
    const size_t MAX_INTEGER_LENGTH = sizeof(int) * 4;
    char szPostfix[] = "_Card.bmp"; 

    for(int i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
        char path[MAX_INTEGER_LENGTH + sizeof(szPostfix) + 1];
        sprintf(path,"%d%s",i, szPostfix);
        cards[i-1] = new Card(i,path);
    }
    ShuffleArray(cards);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        deck->PushTop(cards[i]);
    }
}

void Swap(Card* a, Card* b) {
    Card temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void ShuffleArray(Card** cardArray) {
    srand(dbTimer());
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        Swap(cardArray[i],cardArray[rand()%20]);
}
```

I think where I screwed up is in the `card[i] = new Card(...)` line, but it somehow looks right to me.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

*DISCLAIMER:  I know I should be using the standard library for most of this stuff, but I'm trying to teach myself the hard stuff first.  It's just the way I learn.*

**EDIT:** I fixed the index problem.  Now I've just gotta figure out why some image aren't drawing now...  :/  Thanks for the help!

Comment: For fixed size arrays, you must use automatic object (i.e. `Card card[10][20];`). `new` should be used only when you really need dynamic allocation.

Comment: Your `swap` routine would be better as `void swap(Card *&a, Card *&b) { Card *tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp; }` to save a lot of unnecessary data copying.

Comment: That swap correction fix it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has many problems

1. You are looping with `1 <= i <= 20` but for an array of 20 elements indexing goes from `0 <= index <= 19`. You need to use `cards[i-1] = new Card(i,path);`
2. You are allocating the array of pointers `cards` but you are not deallocating it (memory leak). Either deallocate it with `delete[] cards;` once you are done or just use a stack based array with `Card *cards[20];` instead of allocating it with `new`.
3. The way you compute `MAX_INTEGER_LENGTH` shows you don't really understand what `sizeof` does.
4. This is the reason for which the cards don't get shuffled. You wrote a function that swaps two pointers, but the pointers it is swapping are local variables (parameters) of the function, not the elements of the array. One solution is to pass the parameters as pointer **references** by declaring swap with `void Swap(Card *& a, Card *& b)`, another solution would be passing pointers to pointers (but this would require a more complex syntax of the implementation because of the double indirection and would also require a change in the way you call the function).

Comment: Indices fixed.  Thank you.  But would deleting my array delete the pointers as well?  I'm passing those pointers to another collection; I don't want to delete them until the other collection is done with them, correct?

Comment: What is leaking is the array of pointers used for shuffling (named `cards` in `BuildDeck`). When you delete an array of pointers in C++ the objects that the pointers are pointing to are **not** deleted automatically. As I said in the answer the code is simpler if you just use `Card *cards[20];` instead of allocating it on the heap with `new Card*[20]`. This way when you exit the build function that temporary array is automatically deallocated like other automatic variables.

Answer (score 1):

In the first for loop your starting index is 0, while in the second for loop the starting index is 0. That could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
 for(int i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
        char path[MAX_INTEGER_LENGTH + sizeof(szPostfix) + 1];
        sprintf(path,"%d%s",i, szPostfix);
        cards[i] = new Card(i,path);
    }
```

Here the loop should start from `0` to `20` as:

```
 for(int i = 1 ; i < 21; i++) //incorrect - original code

 for(int i = 0 ; i < 20; i++) //correct - fix
```

And after the fix, you could use `i+1` instead of `i` in :

```
        sprintf(path,"%d%s",i+1, szPostfix);
        cards[i] = new Card(i+1,path);
```

if that is required.